Order (some) observations by specific values
I need to re-order some of the rows of my dataframe. I have a list of observations (names) that I need to be at the top. It's a string variable, and just a selection of them need to be at the top--the rest can be in their existing order.
Example dataset:
df <- data.frame(name = c("Alan", "Betty", "Clyde", "Diane", "Eric", 
                          "Francine", "George", "Harriett"), 
                 height = c(60, 68, 70, 66, 68, 70, 63, 64))

I can't order from lowest to highest or vice versa, and there's no part of the string that is unique to these observations. I only care about the order for some of the observations, not all. And for the ones I do care about, they have to be in a specific order - it's not enough for them to be in the top in the wrong order.
Long version:
df$order[df$name == "Betty"] <- 1
df$order[df$name == "Diane"] <- 2
df$order[df$name == "Alan"] <- 3
df$order[df$name == "Clyde"] <- 4
df <- arrange(df, order)
df$order <- NULL

The above code works, but there are too many observations for me to feel comfortable copy/pasting a bunch of lines.
I tried doing the above code as a for loop (looping either over a list of the names or 1:4), but I couldn't get it to work. Similar for ifelse(). lapply or sapply might work, but frankly I don't understand them.
I'm hoping someone can show me how to loop/automate my solution so it's doable for more observations or show me a different way altogether.

Try match in arrange
> df %>% arrange(match(name, c("Betty", "Diane", "Alan", "Clyde")))
      name height
1    Betty     68
2    Diane     66
3     Alan     60
4    Clyde     70
5     Eric     68
6 Francine     70
7   George     63
8 Harriett     64


I think this is a better solution since it preserves name as character.

And it preserves the original order of the remaining values.

If you have the order of the first few values in a vector nm you can relevel them so they are first:
Edit
Rather than overwrite name you can pass it directly to arrange. This will preserve name as a character vector in the output:
library(forcats)
library(dplyr)

nm <- c("Betty", "Diane", "Alan", "Clyde")

df |>
  arrange(fct_relevel(fct_inorder(name), !!nm))
#       name height
# 1    Betty     68
# 2    Diane     66
# 3     Alan     60
# 4    Clyde     70
# 5     Eric     68
# 6 Francine     70
# 7   George     63
# 8 Harriett     64

fct_inorder() will ensure the original order is preserved, while fct_relevel() will move those names to the top. Without fct_inorder() the remaining names will be in alphabetical order (which is how you have them arranged in your example anyway, but just FYI).

Original Answer
library(forcats)
library(dplyr)

nm <- c("Betty", "Diane", "Alan", "Clyde")

df |>
  mutate(name = fct_relevel(fct_inorder(name), !!nm)) |>
  arrange(name)

Note: name will be a factor variable not a character variable. To return them to character, you can pipe to mutate(name = as.character(name)).

forcats seems a cool tool, never used it before but luckily see it from yours.

@ThomasIsCoding You seem to be doing just fine without it! It is the first package I think of when I think about factors.

Using a named vector
ord <- c("Alan"=3, "Betty"=1, "Clyde"=4, "Diane"=2)

df[order(ord[df$name]),]
      name height
2    Betty     68
4    Diane     66
1     Alan     60
3    Clyde     70
5     Eric     68
6 Francine     70
7   George     63
8 Harriett     64


@ThomasIsCoding's and @LMc's can be combined, too, if staying with the tidyverse is desired for some reason:
df |> 
  arrange(fct_relevel(name, c("Betty", "Diane", "Alan", "Clyde")))


+1, the only caveat to this is that name is first converted to a factor, which by default will order the letters alphabetically. This works in the posted reprex, but has the potential to unexpectedly reorder the remaining values. You can see this by swapping the order of the names George and Harriett in df before running this code.

Thanks, @LMc; your comment underscores that the OP's interest in table order (for a subset of names, at least): Even if name had already been a factor, applying fct_relevel() would have reordered the remaining values in the table — unless the table order already matched the factor order.

Using base::sort_by.
> df |> sort_by(match(df$name, c("Betty", "Diane", "Alan", "Clyde")))
      name height
2    Betty     68
4    Diane     66
1     Alan     60
3    Clyde     70
5     Eric     68
6 Francine     70
7   George     63
8 Harriett     64


wow, learn new function sort_by from you, great! +1!

@ThomasIsCoding Yes they donated it to R 4.4.0!
